# object HTMLInputElement error when trying to display random task

Tags: javascript, arrays, parseint

So I am trying to display and random string from an array I created. The counting portion of my message works, the second part where it should display and random task from my array shows the error. Did I not use the parseInt and Math.random function correctly? I dont have to round the number since parseInt converts it to a integer right?

```
var tasks = []; 

// Function called when the form is submitted.
// Function adds a task to the global array.
function addTask() {
    'use strict';

    // Get the task:
    var task = document.getElementById('task');

    // Reference to where the output goes:
    var output = document.getElementById('output');

    // For the output:
    var message = '';

    if (task.value) {

        // Add the item to the array:
        tasks[tasks.length] = task;

        var randomNum = tasks.length;
        var randomTask = parseInt((Math.random() * randomNum), 10);
        var randomMsg = tasks[randomTask];


        // Update the page:
        message = 'You have ' + tasks.length + ' task(s) in your to-do list.\n';
        message += 'Random Task: ' + randomMsg;

        if (output.textContent !== undefined) {
            output.textContent = message;
        } else {
            output.innerText = message;
        }

    } // End of task.value IF.

    // Return false to prevent submission:
    return false;

} // End of addTask() function.

// Initial setup:
function init() {
    'use strict';
    document.getElementById('theForm').onsubmit = addTask;
} // End of init() function.
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: ok uploaded everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
        tasks[tasks.length] = task;
```

you are adding a reference to the input to the array. So each time it runs, you add another reference to the same input. Perhaps you mean:

```
        tasks[tasks.length] = task.value;
```

so *tasks* is an array of the task names. The rest should be fine, though I'd use:

```
        tasks.push(task.value);
```

and

```
if (typeof output.textContent == 'string') {
  output.textContent = message;
} else {
  output.innerText = message;
}
```